# Windows container volume for AWS ECS under Fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, windows-container

I created a Docker image by extending a Windows Server Core base image and adding an.NET App to it. The resulting container expects a volume to persist data.

I'm using AWS ECS, launching it with Fargate. I have a cluster, a task definition, and an ECR image. I'm able to run the container just fine. I just need to know how to give it a volume.

What type of storage can I use here? And how should I set it up?

Comment: At this time there is no support for persistent volume mounting for Windows tasks on ECS Fargate.

Comment: If I go with EC2, will I be able to use volume mounting for Windows Tasks?

Comment: Yes, with FSx https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/LustreGuide/mounting-ecs.html You could also mount host volumes, but that's not very scalable or fault-tolerant.